# Can "who" and a "noun" go together or should I use "which"?

Tags: word-choice, questions

> "**Who** among the following **singers** is from China?"

1. I would like to know in the aforementioned question, should the noun "**singers**" be included or should it be rephrased to "**Which** of the following singers is from China?"
2. Can "who" and a "noun" go together?

Comment: Which of the following singers is from China? That's the simplest.

Answer (score -1):

1. Practically you can use both as interrogative words: who and which. But each one of them emphasizes something else. When you have choices you should use "which", and when you don't have choice you should use "who". (It is the same for "which" - for choice, and "what" for absent of choice. For example: "What book do you like" Vs. "Which book do you like?")

   - > "**Who** among the following **singers** is from China?" ✔ (We don't have choices)
   - > "**Which** among the following **singers** is from China?" ✔ (We have many singers and we should pick up one of them)
2. Can "who" and a "noun" go together? Yes. The issue isn't the noun but who's behind this noun. Is this noun refers to a person? if the answer is yes then you can use "who". For example: singer, driver, father, mother,  brother, are nouns but these nouns instead of pronouns so they considered as personal pronouns for that purpose.

Comment: If *who* is to be used only when no menu of choices is presented, then it does not belong with *of the following*.

Comment: How can the "who" question not have choices? And why can't we ask a question with "who" if there's choices? The original example sentence seems a conterexample.